# XCODE: Get the Value of a setting

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I almost despair because my settings doesn't save properly.

I save a setting in a UITableView when a user select a cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


checkedCell = indexPath;
NSUInteger row1 = [indexPath row];
NSString *TD = [listData objectAtIndex:row1];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:TD forKey:@"TestData"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"Save");
[tableView reloadData];

}
```

In an other ViewController i load the Data and make a if-else statement:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


NSString *TD = [defaults objectForKey:@"TestData"];

NSLog(@"%@",TD);

if (TD == @"0") {
        NSString *NTD = @"TRUE";
    }
    else {
        NSString *NTD = @"FALSE";

    }
}
```

I see that the NSLog is 0 but NTD is FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make if condition like this

if ([TD isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

```
    NSString *NTD = @"TRUE";

}
else {

    NSString *NTD = @"FALSE";

}
```

Surely this will helpful